# How to find the index of an element in a multidimensional array by JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Converting a JSON array from a PHP array by `json_encode`. I want to find the index of a specific element from that JSON array by JavaScript/JQuery.

First the user will select a option where the values will be the IDs of people.

```
<select class="form-control" id="pname" name="pname" required>
    <option value="">--Please select--</option>
    <option value="312">John Doe</option>
    <option value="313">Mark Angel</option>
    <option value="314">Chloe Karl</option>
</select>
```

Then by JavaScript/JQuery I need to get the index of the value of selected option from the JSON array given below.

```
{
"p_id":{"1":312,"2":313,"3":314},
"p_name":{"1":"John Doe","2":"Mark Angel","3":"Chloe Karl"},
"p_dob":{"1":"1983","2":"1993","3":"1987"},
"p_sex":{"1":"Male","2":"Male","3":"Male"}
}
```

Comment: I don’t see any arrays in your data. Those are all objects. Arrays ar enclosed in `[ ]` in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, actually I am very new to this Json. When I googled to convert php array to json array, I got the suggestion. May be I made mistake.

Comment: What does your PHP array look like and what is the code you're using to convert it?

Comment: Array ( [p_id] => Array ( [1] => 312 [2] => 313 [3] => 314 ) [p_name] => Array ( [1] => Jhon Doe [2] => Mark Angel [3] => Chloe Karl ) [p_dob] => Array ( [1] => 2018 [2] => 1534444200 [3] => 782591400 ) [p_sex] => Array ( [1] => Male [2] => Male [3] => Male ) ) It look something like that.. And I used json_encode to convert it.

Comment: @NeelDebnath I've added an answer for you. Hope this help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstood/misinterpret your question**, Then you need this snippet.

**Steps to do:**

1. Add a `onchange` event on your `select` element first.
2. Parse the json string using `JSON.parse()`
3. Use `Array.prototype.filter()` to get the key/index of the selected user.

```js
function getSelect() {
  var obj = JSON.parse('{"p_id":{"1":312,"2":313,"3":314},"p_name":{"1":"John Doe","2":"Mark Angel","3":"Chloe Karl"},"p_dob":{"1":"1983","2":"1993","3":"1987"},"p_sex":{"1":"Male","2":"Male","3":"Male"}}');
  var ids = obj.p_id;
  var e = document.getElementById("pname");
  var user = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  //console.log(ids, user, Object.keys(ids))
  if(user && user!=""){
    var k = Object.keys(ids).filter((key) => {
      return ids[key] == user;
    })[0];
     console.log(k)
   }else {
     console.log('Select an option first');
   }
  
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" onchange="getSelect()" id="pname" name="pname" required>
  <option value="">--Please select--</option>
  <option value="312">John Doe</option>
  <option value="313">Mark Angel</option>
  <option value="314">Chloe Karl</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is showing an error `Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined` on line `var user = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: @NeelDebnath Did you run may code snippet here on Stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: The error is showing in my workplace, the code is running well in Stackoverflow snippet

Comment: check for the `id` with name `pname`

Comment: It is working now. I just rewrite the <select> html code and repositioned the DOM event from the last to after the classes. Thanks a lot. It is working finally,

Comment: Glad it helps you somehow, best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a javascript object literal not an array, you could use a `for in` loop to iterate and find what you are looking for.

```js
var obj = {
  p_id: { "1": 312, "2": 313, "3": 314 },
  p_name: { "1": "John Doe", "2": "Mark Angel", "3": "Chloe Karl" },
  p_dob: { "1": "1983", "2": "1993", "3": "1987" },
  p_sex: { "1": "Male", "2": "Male", "3": "Male" }
};

var selected = 313;

for (p in obj.p_id) {
  if (obj.p_id[p] == selected) {
    console.log(p);
  }
}
```

If you have the raw response from php, you have then a JSON. You could convert it to object using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Thanks mate. really appreciable.